# Saving state while rotation

Tags: java, android

I Have an app in which the main activity shows a question and has true button false button and cheat button
When user press the correct option, listener will Toast Correct.. and otherwise listener will Toast Incorrect

Now when we press the cheat button new activity is launched and has a textview "Are you sure you want to cheat?", another textview which is blank and a show answer button..

When user presses the show answer button , the blank text view is set to the answer of the question (as asked in the main activity)

And when the user goes back the true and false button onClickListeners are now set to make a toast "Cheating is wrong"

i have declared a boolean value which is set to false, the boolean value is set to True and i save it in the bundle so that when the user rotates the screen , the value of the variable is not overwritten on onCreate(..) method being recalled..

I tried debugging with break points in eclipse , the value is  not overridden still on main activity "Cheating is wrong" doesnt show up , it shows Correct or Incorrect..

QuizActivity : Launcher Activity
CheatActivity: Activity launched on onCreate
TrueFalse activity : creating array of objects with fields (question and answer)

Following is the code : QuizActivity.java (Launcher activity)

```
package com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button mTrueButton, mFalseButton, mNextButton, mCheatButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true) };

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
private boolean mIsCheater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);

        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

            updateQuestion();
            mIsCheater=false;

        }
    });

    mCheatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
            boolean answer = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
            i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answer);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);

    updateQuestion();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

private void updateQuestion() {

    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
    int messageResId = 0;
    if (mIsCheater) {
        messageResId = R.string.judgement_toast;
    } else {
        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
    }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        mIsCheater = data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN,
                false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value of mIsCheater : " + mIsCheater);
    }
}
}
```

The following is the code : CheatActivity.java

```
package com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheatActivity extends Activity {

public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz.anwer_is_true ";
public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz.answer_shown";
public static final String EXTRA_IS_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz.answer_is_shown";
boolean mCorrectAnswer;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswer;
private Boolean mIsAnswerShown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
    mCorrectAnswer = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE,
            false);
    mShowAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
    mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mIsAnswerShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                EXTRA_IS_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
    } else {
        mIsAnswerShown = false;
    }

    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCorrectAnswer) {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);

            } else {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
            }
            setAnswerShownResult(true);
        }
    });

}

public void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    mIsAnswerShown = isAnswerShown;

    data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, mIsAnswerShown);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(EXTRA_IS_ANSWER_SHOWN, mIsAnswerShown);

}

}
```

Following is the code : TrueFalse.java
    package com.mhrsolanki2020.geoquiz;

```
public class TrueFalse {
private int mQuestion;

private boolean mTrueQuestion;

public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {
    mQuestion = question;
    mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;

}

public int getQuestion() {
    return mQuestion;
}

public void setQuestion(int question) {
    mQuestion = question;
}

public boolean isTrueQuestion() {
    return mTrueQuestion;
}

public void setTrueQuestion(boolean trueQuestion) {
    mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html check this link

For orientation support do this in manifest.xml

```
      <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

In Class file, override the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState).